# VS2015: Tooltips stopped showing when hovering on variables in Immediate Window

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015, development-environment, immediate-window

I remember some time ago I could assign a variable in Immediate Window during debug and when hovering mouse over I could see a tooltip with member values just like when hovering over variables in the code.

Now this feature stopped working in my Visual Studio 2015. Did Microsoft remove this feature in VS2015 or I messed something up? Is there a setting for this somewhere in the menus?

**EDIT:** Because not everyone is so sure about this feature ever existing, I add a screenshot from Visual Studio 2012 where you can clearly see the tooltips for text typed in Immediate Window (here I use the variable `web`):
[image: Immediate Window tooltips on hover in Visual Studio 2012]

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I test it in different VS version(VS2012/VS2013/VS2015/VS2017), it really has this issue in VS2015 or VS2017. But it has this feature in VS2012 or VS2013.

I report this issue to the product team here:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/55570/vs2015vs2017-tooltips-stopped-showing-when-hoverin.html

If possible, you could also share your comment there.

Comment: @Mariusz Ignatowicz, I update my answer, I test it in VS2015 or VS2017, it really has no this feature, but the VS2012 or VS2013 supports it. I help you report this feedback to the product team.